# How to handle google oauth with react and express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, token

I want to create api with Express js to handle auth with Google. I have an endpoint that generates url to authenticate with google.

```js
async function signInWithGoogle(req: Request, res: Response) {
  return res.status(200).json({ redirect: getGoogleOAuth2Url() });
}
```

```js
function getGoogleOAuth2Url() {
  const url = new URL(GoogleOAuth2Config.baseUrl);

  url.searchParams.append("client_id", GoogleOAuth2Config.options.client_id);
  url.searchParams.append("access_type", GoogleOAuth2Config.options.access_type);
  url.searchParams.append("redirect_uri", GoogleOAuth2Config.options.redirect_uri);
  url.searchParams.append("response_type", GoogleOAuth2Config.options.response_type);
  url.searchParams.append("scope", GoogleOAuth2Config.options.scope.join(' '));

  return url;
}
```

I have a dilemma how to handle the code that I receive from google which I should use to get access, refresh token and profile info.
There are two ways to solve it:
I can redirect to react app, in react app I read code from url and send it with axios to my express endpoint. Then I get all info I need in express, set access and refresh token cookies, and send profile data as json, so I can set current user data in my authContext in react. But I read that it is bad practice to use google's code on client side.

On the other hand, I can redirect straight to api endpoint and get google's code there without sending it through client. But the problem is how can I receive users data on react client, if I didn't send any axios request. And also how to redirect from api url back to website pages.

```js
async function googleOAuthCallback(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { code } = GoogleOAuthCallbackValidationSchema.parse(req.query);
  try {

    const body = {
      client_id: GoogleOAuth2Config.options.client_id,
      client_secret: GoogleOAuth2Config.clientSecret,
      code: code,
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      redirect_uri: AppConfig.PUBLIC_URL
    }

    const response = axios.post<GoogleOAuthType>(GoogleOAuth2Config.tokenUrl, body);

    return res.status(200).json(response);
  }
  catch (error: any) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

What's way should I use and which one is more secure?